# String to datetime for Google Calendar API

Tags: python, string, api, datetime, calendar

I've gotten some events data from a website and stored the dates and starting times as string variables in python. My aim is to iterate over a for loop and over each iteration, create and add a new event to a google calendar using the Google Calendar API. I've stored the date and start/end times for each event as string variables so theoretically I would have:

```
date='2019-11-01'
start_time='10:00am'
end_time='11:00am'
```

I'd gotten so far until I realised that the way one must format the date and start/end times for an event is as follows:

```
'dateTime': '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00'
```

where if I am not mistaken, the RHS is a datetime object rather than a string. At first I thought I'd try sticking all my strings together with a T in between the date and time out of desperation, but obviously that didn't work because the object isn't supposed to be a string. I was wondering if there was any way I could use the variables I've obtained to create a new google event, or whether I've reached a dead end?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To add an event using Google Calendar's API you need a start_date and an end_date as datetime objects.
The following code creates datetime objects with your strings.
If you print those timeobjects with isoformat. you will see the "T" that you mentioned.

```
import datetime

date='2019-11-01'
start_time='1:20am'
end_time='11:00pm'

start_date_str = date + start_time
end_date_str = date + end_time

start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date_str, '%Y-%m-%d%I:%M%p')
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date_str, '%Y-%m-%d%I:%M%p')

print(start_date.isoformat())
print(end_date.isoformat())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I integrated the .isoformat() into my code but now I'm getting an error: 'Missing time zone definition for start time.' So I defined GMT_OFF = '+00:00' but I'm not quite sure where I should put it for the start and end times. I keep getting 'TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting' when I try to put it at the end of various strings.